# Error 400 mailchimp using script from Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, mailchimp

I'm trying to make a `POST` request through `Google Scripts` script to register members in `mailchimp` through the `API`.

```
var payloadMail = {
    "email_address" : "teste@teste.com.br",
    "status" : "subscribed",
}
var headersMail = {
    'Authorization': 'apikey ******',
    "content-type" : "application/json",
};
var optionsMail = {
    "method" : "post",
    "data" : payloadMail,
    "headers" : headersMail,
}
var respMail = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    "https://us18.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/******/members" ,
    optionsMail);
```

I am sending so, however, it gives this error:

```
{
    "type":"http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/",
    "title":"Invalid Resource",
    "status":400,
    "detail":"The resource submitted could not be validated. For, []]...)
      [0 segundos]
```

When I make the same request by `postman`, then it works.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Compare the headers that the browser is sending with the headers in postman.  Also, double check credentials.

Comment: Both are the same.

Comment: Strange.  And the endpoint URL that the browser is hitting is the same as postman's?

Comment: Yes, it's the same! I suspect that the structure being sent is not valid, but I can not find documentation to correct my doubts. Do you think the structure is correct?

Comment: I found the following when visiting the URL that is in the return error object:  InvalidResource
The resource submitted could not be validated.

For field-specific details, see field_warnings or field_errors objects. This error means that the object submitted to a POST or PATCH request failed to validate against JSON schema, and could relate to campaign, interest group, merge field, or any other available object.

Comment: If your request body is correct, how about modifying from ``"data" : payloadMail,`` to ``"data" : JSON.stringify(payloadMail),``? I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your situation, because I have no document of the API. If this modification was not the solution, can you provide the document of API you want to use?